# Gekko Performance for long time horizon

Tags: gekko

In the code below (PV slope optimization over for the entire year - hourly time step, CSV data download [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/172HaD87t9V_PDElMER4MwDaWyuCZ3KA5/view?usp=sharing)), is there any way to speed up the optimization's performance? Did I model inefficiently? If I set up the "days_to_consider" variable in the code as a low number of days (e.g., 14 days), the optimization can be done relatively fast, but the "days_to_consider" variable is increased to 180+ days, my computer doesn't find the solution.

It is important for me to obtain the solution fast because what I try to do eventually is to simulate the optimal control in microgrids (PV, building, EV, electric battery, etc.).

My code is shown below.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

days_to_consider = 14 # number of days to optimize slope (14 days are ok, 365 days can't be solved)
m.time = np.linspace(0, 24*days_to_consider-1, 24*days_to_consider) # Hourly time step

# Read the weather data from CSV
with open("PV_Input.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
    csv_reader  = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    inputs = [row for row in csv.reader(csv_file)]

#initialize variables
Eb_raw = []
beta_raw = [] # unit: radians
phi_raw = []
Ed_raw = []
Et_r_raw = []

for i in range(2,24*days_to_consider+2):
    Eb_raw.append(float(inputs[i][1])) # solar beam radiation 
    beta_raw.append(float(inputs[i][6])) # solar altitude
    phi_raw.append(float(inputs[i][7])) # solar azimuth
    Ed_raw.append(float(inputs[i][4])) # solar diffuse radiation
    Et_r_raw.append(float(inputs[i][5])) # solar ground reflected

# Assign the time-dependent coefficients
Eb = m.Param(value=Eb_raw) 
beta = m.Param(value=beta_raw)
phi = m.Param(value=phi_raw)
Ed = m.Param(value=Ed_raw)
Et_r = m.Param(value=Et_r_raw)

azimuth = 0.0 # assumed azimuth is fixed, unit: rad
rho_g = 0.14 # reflectance 

area = 100 # PV area 
P_pk = 250 # peak power
p_factor = 0.8 # performance factor

misc = m.Param(value=area * P_pk * p_factor/1000) # area * peak power * performance factor / 1000

# Initialize variables
slope = m.MV(value=0.9225608396276507861, lb=0.0, ub=1.5708) # unit: radian
slope.STATUS = 1
slope.DCOST = 1 # penalty for unnecessary changes
slope.DMAX = 5 # for smooth slope changes

PV_elec = m.SV()

# build PV Equation
cos_theta = m.Intermediate(m.cos(beta)*(m.cos(phi)*m.cos(azimuth)+m.sin(phi)*m.sin(azimuth))*m.sin(slope)+m.sin(beta)*m.cos(slope))           
gamma = m.Intermediate(m.max3(0.45, 0.55+0.437*cos_theta+0.313*(cos_theta)**2))

m.Equation(PV_elec == misc*(Eb*(m.cos(beta)*m.cos(phi)*m.cos(azimuth)*m.sin(slope) \
+ m.cos(beta)*m.sin(phi)*m.sin(azimuth)*m.sin(slope)\
+ m.sin(beta)*m.cos(slope))\
+ Ed*(gamma*m.sin(slope) + m.cos(slope))\
+ 0.5*rho_g*(1-m.cos(slope))*(Eb*m.sin(beta)+Ed)))    

m.Maximize(PV_elec)
m.options.IMODE = 6 # Optimal control
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=True)

# Unit conversion to degree
conversion_rad_to_deg = 180/3.14159265359

slope_in_degree = [i*conversion_rad_to_deg for i in slope]

# Plot the results
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time, PV_elec, 'k')
plt.ylabel('PV Power [kW]')

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.step(m.time, slope_in_degree,'r')
plt.ylabel('slope [deg]')
plt.xlabel('Time [hr]')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Yun Joon, you might want to add the governing equations for the optimizer to work with. You can use `m.Equation()` and write your equations in the parentheses with double equal signs `==`

Comment: Hello Junho, Thank you for your reply. I actually have an equation and forgot to add it here. Let me edit the question now.

Comment: The computation time can be natually increased as the problem demension increases. If your end goal is to have an optimal control, I would set the smaller window in time like 30days and solve the optimization problem within the windows and move to the next window similar to the MPC with a longer horizon.

Comment: I don't understand the second part of the comment (" solve the optimization problem within the windows similar to the MPC with a longer horizon"). If there are any related examples, could you share the links with me? Further, would it make sense to you if I conduct the optimization every month separately? For instance, I conduct the PV slope optimization for January and then February and so on so forth.

Comment: The example codes are little bit long, but you basically want to wrap the m.solve() section with the `for` loop in range of simulation time steps and set the horizon length with `m.time()` in shorter length. That way, the smaller optimization problems are considered at every single `FOR` loop.   https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/NonlinearControl

Comment: If this is a real time control problem that continuosly adjusts the PV slope, then the MPC algorithm would fit well for the perpose.

Comment: I now understand what you said and really appreciate your help. I will re-organize the code with shorter time windows (e.g., monthly, bi-weekly) using a for-loop to find optimal control over the entire year.

Comment: Additionally, I'd like to ask one more question regarding the difference between MPC and optimal control. As far as I know, the difference between MPC and optimal control is that optimal control has a control/prediction horizon equal to 1. In contrast, MPC has the control/prediction horizon >1. Do I know correctly? If I know correctly, I will also apply MPC to this problem.

Comment: MPC is one type of optimization-based control algorithm that allows you to choose the horizon length. It predicts the future behaviors of your system within the horizon by evaluating the governing equations and solves the optimization problem only considering that range. Then, it applys the the first value in your array of your optimization result to the system. Then, it repeats the entire steps for the following time intervals.

Comment: If your system doesn't have any transient behaivor or dynamics, which usually engages the differential equations, then you can do without the prediction steps, niether the horizon. It ends up doing just steady state optimization using the snapshot of the current time step, which I assume you refered to the 'optimal control' above.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about how I can apply MPC to a non-dynamic model (like the PV model in this case)? Is there any similar example in the APMonitor website using Gekko?

Comment: You can do it like what you did in your code with reasonalbly short time horizon. Even if you set the dynamic optimization mode (imode=6), you are still getting the multiple steady-state optimization results for every time point. I hope this helps. Maybe we can get better answer from the others (or, John Hedengren).

Comment: Junho is correct. The only thing limiting the solution from cycle to cycle are dynamics with the `DMAX` for the `MV` in this problem. There are no differential equations. Here is an example that shows `MPC` on a live system: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/TCLabF or introductory code: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DynamicControl

Comment: Thank you Junho and John for all the great comments. I really appreciate it and will study more about dynamic control.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the reason that this problem is challenging is that it is a mixed integer nonlinear programming problem with `max3`. The `max3` function is used to clip `0.55+0.437*cos_theta+0.313*(cos_theta)**2` at the lower bound of 0.45.

[image: lower bound]

The dynamics in your problem are the `DMAX` constraint that limits how fast the angle can change. There are no differential equations in your problem. If there were no `DMAX` constraint then you could solve each time period separately. For the 14 day period, your solution is:

[image: original solution]

It solves with the APOPT solver in about 17 seconds.

```
 Number of state variables:    3350
 Number of total equations: -  2680
 Number of slack variables: -  670
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    0
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Dynamic Control with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:     16.77 NLPi:   76 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    0 Obj: -1.24E+06 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  16.814799999999998 sec
 Objective      :  -1237075.78834978
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

If you reformulate the problem with a slack variable and complementarity constraint then it solves much faster (2.9 seconds) and gives nearly the same solution.

```py
gamma = m.Var(0.5,lb=0.45)
slk = m.Var(lb=0); m.Minimize(1e-3*slk)
m.Equation(slk*(gamma-0.45)<1e-3)
m.Equation(gamma==0.55+0.437*cos_theta+0.313*(cos_theta)**2+slk)
```

It now solves over the entire year (365 days) and requires 133 seconds to solve the problem with 78,831 variables and 61,313 equations.

[image: annual solution]

```
 Number of state variables:    78831
 Number of total equations: -  61313
 Number of slack variables: -  8759
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    8759

EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.

 The solution was found.

 The final value of the objective function is  -4.464484997593126E+7
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :  132.942 sec
 Objective      :  -4.464484990790293E+7
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the complete script.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

#(14 days are ok, 365 days can't be solved)
days_to_consider = 365 # number of days to optimize slope
# Hourly time step
m.time = np.linspace(0, 24*days_to_consider-1, \
                        24*days_to_consider) 

# Read the weather data from CSV
with open("PV_Input.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
    csv_reader  = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    inputs = [row for row in csv.reader(csv_file)]

#initialize variables
Eb_raw = []
beta_raw = [] # unit: radians
phi_raw = []
Ed_raw = []
Et_r_raw = []

for i in range(2,24*days_to_consider+2):
    Eb_raw.append(float(inputs[i][1])) # solar beam radiation 
    beta_raw.append(float(inputs[i][6])) # solar altitude
    phi_raw.append(float(inputs[i][7])) # solar azimuth
    Ed_raw.append(float(inputs[i][4])) # solar diffuse radiation
    Et_r_raw.append(float(inputs[i][5])) # solar ground reflected

# Assign the time-dependent coefficients
Eb = m.Param(value=Eb_raw) 
beta = m.Param(value=beta_raw)
phi = m.Param(value=phi_raw)
Ed = m.Param(value=Ed_raw)
Et_r = m.Param(value=Et_r_raw)

azimuth = 0.0 # assumed azimuth is fixed, unit: rad
rho_g = 0.14 # reflectance 

area = 100 # PV area 
P_pk = 250 # peak power
p_factor = 0.8 # performance factor

# area * peak power * performance factor / 1000
misc = m.Param(value=area * P_pk * p_factor/1000)

# Initialize variables
# unit: radian
slope = m.MV(value=0.9225608396276507861, lb=0.0, ub=1.5708)
slope.STATUS = 1
slope.DCOST = 1 # penalty for unnecessary changes
slope.DMAX = 5 # for smooth slope changes

PV_elec = m.SV()

# build PV Equation
cos_theta = m.Intermediate(m.cos(beta)*(m.cos(phi)\
            *m.cos(azimuth)+m.sin(phi)*m.sin(azimuth))\
            *m.sin(slope)+m.sin(beta)*m.cos(slope))           
gamma = m.Var(0.5,lb=0.45)
slk = m.Var(lb=0); m.Minimize(1e-3*slk)
m.Equation(slk*(gamma-0.45)<1e-3)
m.Equation(gamma==0.55+0.437*cos_theta+0.313*(cos_theta)**2+slk)

m.Equation(PV_elec == misc*(Eb*(m.cos(beta)\
            *m.cos(phi)*m.cos(azimuth)*m.sin(slope) \
            + m.cos(beta)*m.sin(phi)*m.sin(azimuth)*m.sin(slope)\
            + m.sin(beta)*m.cos(slope))\
            + Ed*(gamma*m.sin(slope) + m.cos(slope))\
            + 0.5*rho_g*(1-m.cos(slope))*(Eb*m.sin(beta)+Ed)))    

m.Maximize(PV_elec)
m.options.IMODE = 6 # Optimal control
m.options.SOLVER = 3

#m.options.COLDSTART = 1
#m.solve(disp=True)

m.options.COLDSTART  = 0
#m.options.TIME_SHIFT = 0
m.solve(disp=True)

# Unit conversion to degree
conversion_rad_to_deg = 180/3.14159265359

slope_in_degree = [i*conversion_rad_to_deg for i in slope]

# Plot the results
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time, PV_elec, 'k')
plt.ylabel('PV Power [kW]')

plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.step(m.time, gamma,'b')
plt.plot([0,max(m.time)],[0.45,0.45],'k:')
plt.ylabel('gamma')

plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.step(m.time, slope_in_degree,'r')
plt.ylabel('slope [deg]')
plt.xlabel('Time [hr]')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I never thought of adding a slack variable and learned a new thing. Many appreciated :).